# Display content on the basis of filter value

Tags: php, html

I have created simple page in php which fetch data from database and display on web page.

index.php

```
<?php
  include_once 'dbop.php';
  $objUser = new Users();
  $users = $objUser->get_users();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
   .
   .
   <form action="index.php" method="POST">
      <select name="role" id="role">
        <option value="Admin"><?php echo 'Admin' ?></option>
        <option value="SysAdmin"><?php echo 'SysAdmin' ?></option>
        <option value="User"><?php echo 'User' ?></option>
      </select>
      <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Role</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
            for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($users); $i++) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo ($users[$i]["name"]); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo ($users[$i]["role"]); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
  .
  .
</html>
```

dbop.php

```
<?php
 .
 .
 public function get_users() {
   $sql = "select name, role from users";
   $data = $this->dbObj->ExecuteQuery($sql);
   $data_all = array();
   if ($data != null && mysqli_num_rows($data) > 0) {
     while($fetch_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {
       $arr = array();
       $arr["name] = $fetch_data['name'];
       $arr["role"] = $fetch_data['role'];
       $data_all[] = $arr;
     }
   }
   return $data_all;
 }
?>
```

I want to display the user name and role from database on the basis of selected role (dropdownlist).
like if Admin value selected from dropdownlist then only Admin records need to display on web page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different methods, this is a simplified method :

```
<?php
  include_once 'dbop.php';
  $selected ="";
   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") {
 if ( !isset( $_POST['Filter'] ) ) {
 $selected = $_POST['role'];
 }}

  $objUser = new Users();
  $users = $objUser->get_users();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
   .
   .
   <form action="#" method="POST">
      <select name="role" id="role">
        <option value="Admin"><?php echo 'Admin' ?></option>
        <option value="SysAdmin"><?php echo 'SysAdmin' ?></option>
        <option value="User"><?php echo 'User' ?></option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Filter" >
      </form>

      <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Role</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
            for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($users); $i++) {
                if ($selected !=""){
            if (($users[$i]["role"])== $selected) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo ($users[$i]["name"]); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo ($users[$i]["role"]); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } } }?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  .
  .
</html>
```

Hope this helps.